# Issues reaching usgov SoftLayer API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have attempted this via many different methods and I do not see any issues with non-usgov related SoftLayer accounts. I have come to the conclusion after discussing this with a SoftLayer support person that the usgov SoftLayer accounts use a different domain when connecting. This support person recommended I create this ticket.

Typical Domain: api.softlayer.com
Usgov Domain: api.usgov.softlayer.com

I can only assume this is correct, as I can resolve the usgov domain via ping.
However I cannot reach it via typical means, example:

```
    curl -X GET -u <USER>:<APIKEY> https://api.usgov.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers
```

This instance returns:

```
    curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

https://api.service.usgov.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers

instead

https://api.usgov.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers

Also keep om mind that in order to reach the server you need to use VPN, otherwise you never be able to reach it.

Regards

Comment: So it seems api.usgov.softlayer.com is not reachable via public interface, unlike api.softlayer.com. I found no documentation for this issue, hopefully this question will suffice for future users of this api service.

Comment: yep there is not a public endpoint, and I think it is very understandable that behavior. You know, out there must be a lot people interested to take a look :P.